# What does Swift mean for people learning iOS development for the first time

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, xcode, swift

I quit my job to pursue programming full time and I was planning to take an ios app development course at a college near me that teaches iphone & ipad dev using Objective C. Now that Swift has been released it seems like learning obj C isn't the best choice any more. Apple is saying that swift is supposed to  be easier for newbies to learn but as of right now there are no courses or tutorials to learn it. I have downloaded the swift ibook and it is not beginner friendly AT ALL, its more about teaching you the language and doesn't include any kind of examples of how you implement it to make an actual app. As a beginner where should I start when it comes to learning to develop apps? Is taking an objective C class still worth it?

Thanks in Advance for your advice!

Comment: Swift is a great language to start with, but I would still recommend learning Objective-C down the road ([Joel Spolsky has a great article here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html)). Here is my advice: A programming language isn't something you can learn in two days. Especially if it's one of your first. Start by making other things with Swift like command-line tools. Playgrounds are also good to start with. Once you have a good feel for the language in general, open up a new project and look at Interface Builder. Mac apps are also usually easier than iOS apps.